# How to pass category from custom post type in listbox tinyMCE 4

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce

Bellow this code that to pass category from wordpress default post in tinyMCE 4. already i have done it properly.

```
function list_categories( $cat_id, &$output = array() )
  {
   $categories = get_categories( 'hide_empty=0&orderby=name&order=ASC& parent=' . $cat_id );

foreach( $categories as $cat ) {
    $output[] = array( 'text' => $cat->name, 'value' => $cat->term_id );
    list_categories( $cat->term_id, $output );
}
return $output;
}
$list = list_categories(0); // to get an array of categories

 p_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'mce_options', array( 'categories' => json_encode( list_categories(0) ) ) );

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'mce_admin_scripts' );
function mce_admin_scripts( $hook ) {
if ( $hook == 'post.php' || $hook == 'post-new.php' ) {
    add_action( "admin_head-$hook", 'mce_admin_head' );
}
}
function mce_admin_head() {
echo '<script type="text/javascript">var mce_options=' . json_encode( array( 'categories' => list_categories(0) ) ) . '; </script>';
 }

 {
   type: 'listbox', 
    name: 'sdscategory', 
    label: 'Category', 
    'values': mce_options.categories
    }
```

But my question is that **i need to pass custom category from custom post in tineMCE 4**. like my creating custom post type '**bxcarousel'** & custom category **'bx_carousel_cata'**. I am not expert in php so please help me